# Estimate for composition of compact and injective operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to show the following: Let $X, Y, Z$ be Banach spaces, $K: X\rightarrow Y$ a compact operator and $T:Y\rightarrow Z$ an injective and bounded operator: Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $C<\infty$ so that $\forall x\in X$:
\begin{equation}
||Kx||_Y\leq \epsilon ||x||_X+C||TKx||_Z
\end{equation}
I was trying to figure out how to use the injectivity, but can anyone show me a way to prove this?

Comment: This is a standard exercise. What have you tried? First idea would be to try proof by contradiction.

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440847/inequality-for-compact-operator-between-banach-spaces?rq=1